# Extract Hyperlinks from selected Outlook emails to a Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, hyperlink

I found this VBA Outlook code that meets my purpose in theory. `objHyperlink` seems to return Nothing when I debug.

The outputs are always empty and during debug I get

> Runtime error: "13" and Type mismatch

at the line - `For Each objHyperlink In objMailDocument.Hyperlinks`

```vb
Dim objExcelApp As Excel.Application
Dim objExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim objExcelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

Sub ExportAllHyperlinksInMultipleEmailsToExcel()
    Dim objSelection As Selection
    Dim objMail As MailItem
    Dim objMailDocument As Document
    Dim objHyperlink As Hyperlink
    Dim i As Long
 
    Set objSelection = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
 
    If Not (objSelection Is Nothing) Then
 
        Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set objExcelWorkbook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Add
        Set objExcelWorksheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        objExcelApp.Visible = True
        objExcelWorkbook.Activate
 
        With objExcelWorksheet
            .Cells(1, 1) = "Email"
            .Cells(1, 2) = "Text"
            .Cells(1, 3) = "Link"
            .Cells(1, 4) = "Source"
        End With
 
        i = 0
        For Each objMail In objSelection
            Set objMailDocument = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
            If objMailDocument.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then              <- Correct # of links shown here
                For Each objHyperlink In objMailDocument.Hyperlinks    <- Debug highlights this 
                    If InStr(objHyperlink.Address, "www.") > 0 Then
                        i = i + 1
                        Call ExportToExcel(i, objMail, objHyperlink)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
            objMail.Close olDiscard
        Next
 
        objExcelWorksheet.Columns("A:D").AutoFit
    End If
End Sub

Sub ExportToExcel(n As Long, objCurrentMail As MailItem, objCurrentHyperlink As Hyperlink)
    Dim nLastRow As Integer
 
    nLastRow = objExcelWorksheet.Range("A" & objExcelWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 
    objExcelWorksheet.Range("A" & nLastRow) = n
    objExcelWorksheet.Range("B" & nLastRow) = objCurrentHyperlink.TextToDisplay
    objExcelWorksheet.Range("C" & nLastRow) = objCurrentHyperlink.Address
    objExcelWorksheet.Range("D" & nLastRow) = objCurrentMail.Subject
End Sub
```

Comment: Just a guess but try Dim objMailDocument As Word.Document
    Dim objHyperlink As Word.Hyperlink

Comment: Thanks for your guess @CDP1802 - This change makes it stop on Call ExportToExcel(i, objMail, objHyperlink) - It does seem to capture links in objHyperlink.Address this way though, but is not able to pass it forward to Excel.

Comment: Maybe you need to change to Word.Hyperlink in the parameter list also.

Comment: You are correct. This seems to have done the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @CDP1802 for pointing out a couple of changes to try. This does work with the following code:

```
Dim objExcelApp As Excel.Application
Dim objExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim objExcelWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

Sub ExportAllHyperlinksInMultipleEmailsToExcel()
Dim objSelection As Selection
Dim objMail As MailItem
Dim objMailDocument As Word.Document   << Added Word. here
Dim objHyperlink As Word.Hyperlink     << Added Word. here
Dim i As Long

Set objSelection = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

If Not (objSelection Is Nothing) Then

   Set objExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
   Set objExcelWorkbook = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Add
   Set objExcelWorksheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
   objExcelApp.Visible = True
   objExcelWorkbook.Activate

   With objExcelWorksheet
            .Cells(1, 1) = "Email"
            .Cells(1, 2) = "Text"
            .Cells(1, 3) = "Link"
            .Cells(1, 4) = "Source"
  End With

  i = 0
  For Each objMail In objSelection
      Set objMailDocument = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
      If objMailDocument.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
         For Each objHyperlink In objMailDocument.Hyperlinks
             If InStr(objHyperlink.Address, "www.") > 0 Then
                i = i + 1
                Call ExportToExcel(i, objMail, objHyperlink)
             End If
         Next
      End If
      objMail.Close olDiscard
  Next

  objExcelWorksheet.Columns("A:D").AutoFit
End If
End Sub

Sub ExportToExcel(n As Long, objCurrentMail As MailItem, objCurrentHyperlink As Word.Hyperlink) << Added Word. here
    Dim nLastRow As Integer
 
    nLastRow = objExcelWorksheet.Range("A" & objExcelWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1


objExcelWorksheet.Range("A" & nLastRow) = n
objExcelWorksheet.Range("B" & nLastRow) = objCurrentHyperlink.TextToDisplay
objExcelWorksheet.Range("C" & nLastRow) = objCurrentHyperlink.Address
objExcelWorksheet.Range("D" & nLastRow) = objCurrentMail.Subject
End Sub
```